# It's possible to create pod dynamically in kubernetes local cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Hi i am new to kubernetes.

I want to create dynamically pod when an event occured.for example when a push a file in directory.i
want to create pod dynamically to process this file.I work in a local cluster(minikube)

Comment: This can be implemented using the Kubernetes API. The exact implementation will depend on how much programming resources you have, the event source, and your kubernetes cluster configuration.

Comment: can i use kubernetes api inside a pod.

Comment: @AndreKouame take a look on official documentation regarding [Access Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)

Comment: @AndreKouame yes, you will need to provide the correct permissions to a service account via RBAC, and then bind that service account to the Pod that you want to run with said permissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a service that continuously keeps on monitoring your directory and provision pod for provisioning it.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to create a pod

> when a push a file in directory

What do you mean by *push* ? You mean using an SCM like Git for example ?

Anyway, this seems a basic CI/CD workflow to me. You can certainly do it using the Kubernetes API as told in comment but (in my opinion) it will be more simple to just do it with your CI/CD tool (supposing you're using one).

If not, here are some hints :

- If you're using Git, then you should have a look at [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/)
- If you're not using Git, then you should look at [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)

Those are not the only existing tools, but probably the most popular with the most help and documentation out there.